# Every interval is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, measurable-sets

The proof is given below:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

But I do not understand why we assumed that $a$ does not belong to $A$, could anyone explain this for me please?

Also I guess that we divided $I_{k}$ into 2 intervals be $a$ is not in $A$.... am I correct?

Thanks!

Comment: They explain it in the proof: "Otherwise..."

Comment: No they did not say why, they said if it is in $A$ just replace it from $A$ @amsmath

Comment: Yes, that's a way to say why.

Comment: No it is a way for dealing with the set $A$ if it contains $a$ .... delete $a$ from it @amsmath

Comment: Otherwise you need to intersect with $(-\infty,a]$ when defining $A_1$ and $I_k'$, but they want $I_k'$ to be open.

Comment: @hopefully Well, then no. If you think so. But then deal with it. It's a trivial argument. You get a minus from me.

Comment: @hopefully: It is a convenience that lets the resulting 'split' intervals remain open. Another approach would be to show that the intervals may be taken to be any interval, not just open. Different authors take different approaches.

Comment: @amsmath: Seems a little harsh for a reasonable question?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, the question is fine. But I don't like the way OP reacts to my comments that are supposed to help them.

Comment: It is explained in the proof.  If $a \notin A$, great.  If, on the other hand, $a\in A$, then replace the set $A$ with the set $A \setminus \{a\}$.  Since the two sets differ by only a single point, the outer measure will be unchanged.  The reason to do this is to avoid some silly pedantry later on in the proof.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: My take on this question is that the OP is asking **why** (as in what is the purpose in the proof) are they (the proof authors)  assuming that $a \notin A$.

Comment: My professor proved this theorem without assuming that $a$ is not in $ A$, this is why I am asking @copper.hat